# Generating PostgreSql large database backup using pg_dump in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I am Using Postgresql for my PHP project which is built in Codeigniter, the size of this database is very large there are upto 500 tables in my project i have used the utility class for backup but it failed due to size of database now in google search i found a solution pg_dump , but can't find a suitable example for my problem. Here is my code but it only generate an empty sql file.

```
$username = $this->db->username;
    $password = $this->db->password;
    $hostname = $this->db->hostname;
    $dbname   = $this->db->database;

    $dataDir  = DB_BACKUP;
    $pgDumpDir = "/usr/bin/pg_dump";
    $dated = date('d-m-Y');
    $fileName = $dataDir . "backup_" . $dated . ".sql";
    $command = $pgDumpDir;
    $command .=" --username ".$username;
    $command .= " ".$dbname." > ".$fileName;
    echo "ok " . shell_exec($command);
```

Comment: What is "very large"? How many TB are we talking about?

Comment: This is an ERP System.

Comment: Echo the value of `$command`. Is it sane? Also, you assign a value to `$hostname`, but you don't use it.

Comment: It doesn't matter (a lot) what kind of system it is, it's about the size of the database when you think size matters. So, what size is it? PHP might stop running after a while, just because of configuration settings in PHP and webserver.

Comment: Actually the command is ok and this one also generating an empty sql file. May be the problem will be operating system because i am running this command on Window may be this should work in Linux.